# When does WebRTC RTCDataChannel readyState becomes open?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peer

I have created a simple prototype in WebRTC that uses test STUN servers provided by Google:

```
var servers = [
   "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
   ...
];
```

I ran two separate apps (without a local server - i.e. NodeJS).
I just opened the file directly via web browser.

It successfully created a `RTCPeerConnection` and `RTCDataChannel` objects.

However, `onopen` handler in `RTCDataChannel` was never triggered.
The `readyState` of the data channel is always "connecting".

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```
  window.localConnection = localConnection =
      new RTCPeerConnection(configuration); // configuration.iceServer

  localChannel = localConnection.createDataChannel('data');
  localChannel.onopen = function () { // never triggered
     var readyState = localChannel.readyState;
     console.log('Local channel state is: ' + readyState);
  }
```

**QUESTIONS:**
1. Do I need a server (like NodeJS) to have a `readyState` set to "open"?
2. When would `readyState` transition to "open" state?

Comment: Are you doing the rest of the RTC negotiation as well…? I.e. exchanging SDP offers and ICE candidates?

Comment: @deceze, yes add track, offer, set descriptor, answer and add ice candidate. they all work fine. but I can't send for the data channel is not open.

Comment: @deceze, question. in this [sequence diagram](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/images/ladder-2party-simple.svg), 15 will send offer to the remote connection. Is this via data channel?

Comment: No. That is still part of the negotiation and exchanging of ICE candidates which must complete in order to establish a connection. Data channels then go over an established connection.

Comment: @deceze, thank you for confirming. I used Node.js for my Signaling server. atleast it cleared my confusion about #7 in the sequence.